# Is it possible to translate "trying to get property of non object" error in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, yii1.x

I'm developing CRM application using PHP code, i need to translate the error 'trying to get property of non object'  to french translate.

I am using YII framework.

**Note: try/catch block does not catch this error.**

Can anybody provide me an idea to translate this error ?

Comment: if your array variable is not an object and you trying to get it's parameter inthis way ($object->parameter), then error occur, When you call $object->property, PHP is assuming you're accessing an object property

Comment: First off, you cant catch these as they are not **Exceptions** but a **Notices**. Then, you can have a custom error handler to catch the notices, but then again it wont make any difference as it wont work with `error_reporting=0` and you have `error_reporting` turned off for the production ENV. **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Try-Catch Statement for this. Just catch the error and throw your own msg.

```
try {
   // YOUR CODE TO GET PROPERTY FROM OBJECT WHICH DOES NOT EXIST
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "On ne voit bien qu’avec le cœur. L’essentiel est invisible pour les yeux.";
 //NEXT LINE PRINTS THE REAL ERROR MSG
 //echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Then you could try to check the object with isset() or smth and then " throw new Exception("bla");"

Comment: `try{}catch(){}` are for `Exceptions` only not for **Notices**, this is not correct any how.